# File reading failed with no clear reason - Java

Tags: java, eclipse, file

I am trying to read a text document with one line of writing in and turned to my Java help book to see how. I copied the code and got the message "a read error has occurred", meaning the operation had clearly failed and gone to the catch block (I haven't put in a proper exception event yet).
I believe it's something stupidly simple which I've done wrong, but here is my code.

```
try
    {
        FileReader version = new FileReader( "version.txt" ) ;

        BufferedReader bufferV = new BufferedReader(version);

        String versionS = "" ;

        while( ( versionS = bufferV.readLine() ) != null )
        {
            System.out.println( versionS ) ;
        }

        bufferV.close() ;
    }
    catch( IOException e )
    {
        System.out.println( "A read error has occurred." ) ;
    }
```

If it helps to know, this is part of an eclipse project saved in my dropbox. Every application has full read/write control over the folder and I have ownership over it. The text document is in the same directory as the source code (and along side the class file in the compiled version.

Comment: Stop catching the exception and ignoring its message and stack trace, and you'll get the clear reason why the exception happens. Replace the content of the catch block by `throw new RuntimeException(e);`

Comment: getting the error would help. Try putting e.printStackTrace for the error rather the System.out.println

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies here:

> The text document is in the same directory as the source code

Putting the file in the source folder will not help as the code will look for file in the current directory and not in source path. So move your file in either your project base dir as java code in eclipse will be able to read it from there.

Comment: No, it won't look for the file in the classpath. It will look for the file in the current directory, which is the directory from which the java command is launched. And no, a file path can't point to two different locations.

Comment: Thanks. Knew it would be something stupidly simple. I did the same thing with an image yesterday.

Comment: @JBNizet Yeah your are right classpath wouldn't matter unless we don't use the classloader to read the stream.